# Permission denied on Centos7, Apache, Mod Passenger and Ruby 2.6.3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I never tried working with Cent-OS for hosting my Rails applications. I was using before and now I got a server which is running Cent-OS 7. I installed Apache, Phusion Passenger, RVM, Ruby 2.6.3 and bundle updated the Rails app. Everything was fine up to this.

I added the Virtual-Host and restarted the Apache2 server, I got 403 Forbidden message from the browser.

Also I checked the error_log I got the following errors.

```
[Tue Feb 11 08:34:14.377938 2020] [core:error] [pid 125490] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.69.78.16:30474] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/santosh/sites') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 11 08:34:14.593925 2020] [core:error] [pid 125490] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.69.78.16:30474] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/santosh/sites') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

The virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com.np
        ServerAlias www.domain.com.np
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>
        # ModPagespeed on
        # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
        DocumentRoot /home/santosh/sites/app/public
        PassengerRuby /home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/wrappers/ruby

        # Relax Apache security settings
        <Directory /home/santosh/sites/app/public>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
                # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the permission of the app directory is as:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 4 santosh santosh        31 May 18  2019 app
```

I couldn't figure out what I am missing. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the folder permissions on the server, try running 'ls -l' on your folder.

Comment: Yes, the permission is `drwxrwxr-x. 4 santosh santosh`. I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: chmod 755 -R on santosh just in case sub-directories have the wrong permission. -R is recursive and will apply the permission to all sub-directories.

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm